# ip to server communication options

Tags: ubuntu

There are situations, particularly within the web, where an http request is sent from the browser to the server. Yet there are no name-based virtual hosts to handle the ip/port number that was requested in. So how does Ubuntu Server handle it when it is requested yet its apache configuration doesn't have any name-based virtual hosts to handle the request? What does Ubuntu do next?

Answer (score 1):

If you can ping a server, it only means that it answers to ICMP echo request. This is handled by the network stack of the linux kernel.

Comment: My question not related to ping command. Im just wondering what way does the server respond to an ip address other than virtual hosts.

Comment: So its about HTTP-Requests, name-based virtual hosts and how your Webserver handles request if the header doesn't contain a domain name in the _Host: ..._ field?

Comment: Yes its about http requests and how the server handles them when no name-based virtual hosts is specified.

Comment: Ok, so please edit your question and don't forget to mention what webserver you use.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This one one example of discovering what is serving files on port 80:

---

```
root@server:~# netstat -lantp | grep 80
tcp     0     0.0.0.0:80           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      475/nginx
```

---

This tells me the web server Nginx is running and bound to IP 0.0.0.0 (all IPv4 IPs hosted by the server) on port 80. The "p" netstat parameter requires root, it will show you the process ID# and name.